# How to solve sudo: port: command not found (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, zsh, xmgrace

I updated macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3 that uses zsh. While installing openmotif to have Xmgrace after that I found this sudo: port: command not found. I dont know how to pass through.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) documentation.

You just need to Install MacPorts for MacOS Big Sur v11

It helped me to go through the same error msg when I tried to have coreutils installed (via "sudo port install coreutils") in my MacOS.